# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;

Tags: actionbarsherlock

i use ActionBarLibrary in a library, that I use in a my app

i got this message when i try to compil

[2013-01-28 16:09:46 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;
[2013-01-28 16:09:46 - comfree] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;

Comment: You are importing the same library more than once. Just to let you know, ActionBarSherlock has been deprecated for some time.

Answer (score 0):

As asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742602/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-actionbarsherlock-rattr), I was facing the exact same error yesterday. I pinpointed the cause of the error to /bin/classes. If I deleted the /classes dir before running the app, the app would compile and run. Of course, when I tried to actually export the app, the /classes dir would come back and along with it the error.

The solution to my problem was to install the latest version of Eclipse. You will then need to install the latest version of the ADT but all the Android versions you have downloaded earlier for the other Eclipse installation will be detected and used for this one as well. When I export or run the app through Eclipse, the /classes folder does not appear now.

Answer (score 0):

right click on project to go project property>>java Build path>>choose Order and Export and then Unselect all except android4.0 or what every you have then clean and build your project ,now error not come again..

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that I deleted the jar files which I copy pasted in project's lib folder. I explicitly imported external jars in build path